# Sign in to organisation or university via linux server

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-server, login-page

I've got an Ubuntu server on my workstation in an university.
I need to sign in via entering user name and password on a login page to connect to the internet.
How can I do this on the Ubuntu server when there is no terminal browser preinstalled on it (ain't got internet access)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can use CURL (a command line tools) to authenticate your account for internet access.

[Learn more](https://curl.se/)